# "no CUDA-capable device is detected" with CUDA-capable GPU installed Win7

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have installed cuda.7.0.28 into my laptop. I tried to run one of the sample file. I ran deviceQuery project and got this message:

```
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
Result = FAIL
```

Then, I ran nvidia-smi.exe file and got this message:

[image]

As you see, it is written that "Not Supported". What should I do?

Comment: The "Not Supported" in the nvidia-smi output is completely normal for a consumer GPU running the standard WDDM driver and unrelated to your problem

Comment: You may have an optimus laptop which has the NVIDIA GPU switched off.  The cuda deviceQuery program will then report that no device is detected.  The nvidia-smi program output indicates that the driver is properly installed and the GPU is properly detected.  If you have an optimus laptop, you'll need to learn how to run [CUDA apps under optimus](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/optimus-developer-guide/index.html#abstract), or else see if there is an option in your system BIOS to switch the NVIDIA GPU on all the time.

Answer (score 1):

nvidia-smi returning 'not supported' does not necessarily mean that your GPU does not have the ability to run CUDA code. It means that you don't have the ability to see the active CUDA process name using nvidia-smi.

Cuda-z might be of help here. Take a look at what it is here: http://cuda-z.sourceforge.net/

Also, I have to say I had quite a few problems getting CUDA running on Windows. If you really need to run it on Windows, make sure you go through this first: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/#axzz3cNkYKZDP

Have you tried to run it on linux on the same machine? It was much easier to get it workinge.

Comment: I tried to install CUDA in ubuntu using virtual machine. In the beginning of the installation, it said that  `This might cause some serious problems on your computer ` . Do you recommend keep going installation?

Comment: I've seen people installing CUDA in Virtual machines without problems. This guide actually teaches you how to install Cuda and use caffe (python package) on a virtual machine: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-14.04-VirtualBox-VM. I would recommend creating a small partition in your disk and installing Linux for your work - I think it will pay off over time as I've found most open source code I encountered works better in Linux.

Comment: I accomplished installing cuda in ubuntu using virtual machine.  I took a snaphot before restarting the machine. After restarting the machine, it cannot open ubuntu. It gets stuck in that status.

Comment: Unless you take special steps (e.g. PCI Passthrough), and have the proper setup, you can't use a GPU in a VM.  Note the instruction in the the linked guide:  "Do NOT install the graphics card drivers (since we are in a virtual machine)" and "(In a virtual machine we do not have access to the the GPU)"  So this isn't really a sensible suggestion if the goal is to actually be able to use the GPU in that laptop (or any GPU) for CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

NVIDIA now provide a toolkit to install CUDA on windows (Linux or Mac also).  It does a handy check of your system, to see if it meets necessary requirements for CUDA if you are unsure about your GPU

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive

Answer (score -3):

I've noticed that when my nvidia driver is updated during the system package update process (on Ubuntu) that I'll get this message.  It is resolved by a reboot, or likely an X restart although I haven't tried that.

This was disconcerting the first time it happened since it was one of those "Hey!  My code just ran fine.  WTF happened?" moments.